# this in java class (pointers)JAVA

Tags: java, class, pointers, this

```
public class Try {
    String name="";
    int age=13;
    public void changer(Try t) {
        t = this;
    }
}
```

what does `t=this` do in this code?
I know this normally refers to the starting variable in top but int his case it looks like it does nothing?

Comment: I am sorry I am just a newbie.

Comment: It assigns `this` to the local variable `t` and then returns, so essentially nothing.

Comment: okay , so it doesnt point to any adress in data? if we assign two objects called t1 and t2 and say : t1=t2 it point to that adress am I right? but not in this case?

Comment: In this case, ``t = this;`` does nothing. It doesn't change the value of the parameter t of the calling method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`this` always refers to the current object**, you can refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

> What does t=this do in this code?

It will assign the provided reference of `t` to the current object.

> I know this normally refers to the starting variable in top but int
>   his case it looks like it does nothing ?

No, you are wrong, this does NOT refer to the starting variable in top, rather as mentioned above, it refers to the current object.

**The most common usage of `this` is to initialize the variables of an object by using the constructor, as shown below:**

```
public class Try {
    String name; //initialize using constructor
    int age; //initialize using constructor

    //constructor
    public Try(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name; //assigns passed name value to current object's name
        this.age = age; //assigns passed age value to current object's age
    }
}
```

**So It doesn't point to any address in data?**

`this` holds the reference (think like a pointer in `C`) of the current object.

**If we assign two objects called t1 and t2 and say : t1=t2 it point to that address am I right? but not in this case?**

Yes, if you assign `t1=t2` then you are making `t1` to point to the same object as `t2` i.e., both `t1` and `t2` refer the same object on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

`t= this` means you are assigning to local variable `t` the current constructor object.
`this` refers to the current object.